Select a Text for CSS
I am learning WordPress Plugin Development. I have below HTML in a Admin Panel Page.
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">My Text</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes">
    </p>
</form>

How can I select My Text uniquely so that other Admin Panel pages will not affected ?

Start by creating a stylesheet for your plugin.Then you can use the do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts') to enqueue it in the controlpanel only, avoiding it to be loaded in the frontend.
You could do something like this:
function my_plugin_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin-admin-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/css/admin-style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_admin_styles');

Just make sure to correct the path for your stylesheet. In the code above, it's assumed the stylesheet is in an "assets" folder - and in a "css" folder within the assets-folder. Also, I would highly recommend to rename the function name - and the style ID "my-plugin-admin-style" to something more fitting for your plugin.
Then you can add the classes to your optionspage, and style them in the stylesheet without messing anything else up - as long as the classes are unique.

Thanks @WPTricksDK. Actually I would like to select uniquely so that  other Admin Panel pages will not affected. Not Frontend pages.
These are an Admin Panel Page HTML code.
Can you help me in this regard ?

Hi @Foysal - as long as you're adding custom class-names, no other admin-page will be affected by your stylesheet. Eg. you can add the class "my-very-special-class" to the  - and as long as you make sure to target elements within that class, you're good.
